# JLabel opaque and alpha

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

In JPanel I have few JLabels created like this:

```
...
Random rand = new Random();
Color col = new Color(rand.nextFloat(),
rand.nextFloat(),
rand.nextFloat(),
rand.nextFloat());
Color playColor= new Color(col.getRed(), col.getGreen(), col.getBlue(), col.getAlpha());
sqr.setOpaque(true);
sqr.setBackground(playColor);
sqr.setLayout(null);
...
```

When I click on any JLabel (mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)) I can get information about it in JOptionPane. In the same JOptionPane I have checkBox to mark selected label (check-> setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red)), uncheck -> setBorder(null). When I check and then uncheck jLabel, somethink like this is happened:

[image]

How to rid of these checkBoxes from labels?

edit: checkBoxes on labels are only pictures, not real checkBoxes. Maybe this picture will help:
[image]

This square with red border is now check by chechBox Mark on JOptionPane. And this one on left (with checkBox picture on it) was checked earlier. I don't know how explain this, it just happens after I click on checkBox Mark on JOptionPane. After click I set red border or set border null on label, nothing more.

Comment: An SSCCE would be nice. I don't completely understand the problem.

Comment: A little more code would be helpful here.

Comment: BTW, why use the -> operator?? That's Java not C++

Comment: @ignis, this fragment with arrow it's not a code :) I just wrote that to explain what check option is doing. Sorry for misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2):

As an aside, (this probably should be a comment, but I'm using an answer for the code blocks) this..

```
Color col = new Color(
    rand.nextFloat(),
    rand.nextFloat(),
    rand.nextFloat(),
    rand.nextFloat());
Color playColor= new Color(col.getRed(), col.getGreen(), col.getBlue(), col.getAlpha());
```

..is equivalent to..

```
Color playColor = new Color(
    rand.nextFloat(),
    rand.nextFloat(),
    rand.nextFloat(),
    rand.nextFloat());
```

Answer (score 1):

Those check boxes won't  'just appear' there so precisely. Are you drawing them somewhere at the labels?! Please check this thoroughly!

A little more code would be useful.

Comment: check boxes on labels are only picture of real checkBox. They appears after I check and uncheck checkbox in jPanel. I don't draw them.

Comment: Just show us more code please! I don't care about the Color things and everything. Show us exactly how the elements are layed out in the JPanel and such.